# What is the difference between "We are going to study" and "We are going to be studying"?

Tags: future, will-be-going

I want to know when we use "be going to" + be + ing?

Comment: No. It's not about the future.

Comment: The tense doesn't matter—the principle is the same between the use of the infinitive and the present participle.

Comment: No relevant difference.

Answer (score 0):

The second construction is usually used in reference to a particular point in time (in the future), whereas the first construction is used to refer to an indefinite period of time in the future.

*e.g.* We are going to be studying when they arrive.  After they have left, we are going to study.